# Calculating columns using number strings in column names, data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a table (called money_table) with many columns with a financial year suffix in their name:

```
ID    LunchMoney_1213   DinnerMondey_1213    LunchMoney_1314    DinnerMondy_1314
01                 12                  24                 17                  18
02                234                  12                 43                  44
03                 14                  19                  2                  12
```

I need to make new columns adding the LunchMoney and DinnerMoney amounts for the relevant year, and delete the old columns. The idea is to end up with this:

```
ID    TotalMoney_1213    TotalMoney_1314
01                 36                 35
02                246                 87
03                 33                 14
```

I am using data.table because the table is very large, and I can do what I want using the following code:

```
money_table[,':='(TotalMoney_1213 = LunchMoney_1213 + DinnerMoney_1213,
                  TotalMoney_1314 = LunchMoney_1314 + DinnerMoney_1314)][,c(LunchMoney_1213,DinnerMoney_1213, LunchMoney_1314, DinnerMoney_1314) := NULL]
```

But there are many years, so writing it all out like this would take too long. I know there must be a way to use the numbers in the column names and do this more efficiently, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think pivoting (longer), summarizing, then unpivoting (wider) works. (I wonder if keeping it in *long* form might be better in the long run, over to you.)

```r
library(data.table)
money_table <- setDT(structure(list(ID = 1:3, LunchMoney_1213 = c(12L, 234L, 14L), DinnerMondey_1213 = c(24L, 12L, 19L), LunchMoney_1314 = c(17L, 43L, 2L), DinnerMondy_1314 = c(18L, 44L, 12L)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame"))

dcast(
  melt(money_table, id.vars = "ID"
    )[, yr := paste0("TotalMoney_", gsub(".*_", "", variable))
    ][, .(value = sum(value)), by = .(ID, yr)
    ],
  ID ~ yr, value.vars = "value")
#       ID TotalMoney_1213 TotalMoney_1314
#    <int>           <int>           <int>
# 1:     1              36              35
# 2:     2             246              87
# 3:     3              33              14
```

If you're already using `magrittr` for other things (whether with `dplyr` or not ... I use it with `data.table` all the time), this can be slightly more readable as:

```r
library(magrittr)
melt(money_table, id.vars = "ID") %>%
  .[, yr := paste0("TotalMoney_", gsub(".*_", "", variable))] %>%
  .[, .(value = sum(value)), by = .(ID, yr)] %>%
  dcast(., ID ~ yr, value.vars = "value")
```

Comment: Good approach with `dcast` + `melt`, upvoted!

Comment: you could also use `money_table[, melt(.SD, id.vars="ID")]` and `.[, dcast(.SD, ID ~ year, value.vars="value")]` to keep everything inside one chain of `[]` queries

Comment: Nice trick, thank you @MichaelChirico!

Answer (score 2):

We can try `data.table` with `split.default`

```
> dt[, lapply(split.default(.SD, paste0("TotalMoney_", gsub(".*_", "", names(.SD)))), sum), ID]
   ID TotalMoney_1213 TotalMoney_1314
1:  1              36              35
2:  2             246              87
3:  3              33              14
```

Comment: This may be more memory-efficient than the double-pivoting of mine. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

With development version 1.14.3, [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) has gained a `measure()` function which is useful for melting data that has several distinct pieces of information *encoded in each column name* (as requested by the OP).

Furthermore, aggregation is done within the call to `dcast()` which saves an additional aggregation step.

```
library(data.table) # development version 1.14.3 used here
melt(money_table, measure.vars = measure(money, year, sep = "_"))[
    , dcast(.SD, ID ~ paste0("TotalMoney_", year), sum)]
```

> ```
>    ID  TotalMoney_1213  TotalMoney_1314
> 1:  1               36               35
> 2:  2              246               87
> 3:  3               33               14
> ```

The call to `measure()` tells `melt()` to split the column names into two parts, the name part (called `money`) and the `year` part:

```
melt(money_table, measure.vars = measure(money, year, sep = "_"))
```

> ```
>     ID       money year value
>  1:  1  LunchMoney 1213    12
>  2:  2  LunchMoney 1213   234
>  3:  3  LunchMoney 1213    14
>  4:  1 DinnerMoney 1213    24
>  5:  2 DinnerMoney 1213    12
>  6:  3 DinnerMoney 1213    19
>  7:  1  LunchMoney 1314    17
>  8:  2  LunchMoney 1314    43
>  9:  3  LunchMoney 1314     2
> 10:  1 DinnerMoney 1314    18
> 11:  2 DinnerMoney 1314    44
> 12:  3 DinnerMoney 1314    12
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
money_table <- fread("
ID    LunchMoney_1213    DinnerMoney_1213    LunchMoney_1314    DinnerMoney_1314
01                 12                  24                 17                  18
02                234                  12                 43                  44
03                 14                  19                  2                  12")
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest transforming your dataframe to tidy format where each column is a variable:

```
money_table %>%
  gather("key", "value", c(-ID)) %>%                          # Wide -> Long format
  separate(key, into = c("type", "year"), sep = "_") %>%   # Split what used to be colum names into type and year
  spread(type, value) %>%                                  # DinnerMoney and LunchMoney are now two separate variables with values for each year
  group_by(ID, year) %>%                                   # Group by ID and year
  summarize(DinnerMoney = sum(DinnerMoney),                # Sum up DinnerMoney for each year as well as LunchMoney for each year
            LunchMoney = sum(LunchMoney)) %>%
  mutate(total_value = DinnerMoney + LunchMoney)           # Get total value for each year

# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   ID [3]
     ID year  DinnerMoney LunchMoney total_value
  <int> <chr>       <int>      <int>       <int>
1     1 1213           24         12          36
2     1 1314           18         17          35
3     2 1213           12        234         246
4     2 1314           44         43          87
5     3 1213           19         14          33
6     3 1314           12          2          14
```

If you want total  values for each years as columns, you can pivot this table like this:

```
money_table %>%
  select(ID, year, total_value) %>%
  spread(year, total_value)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
     ID `1213` `1314`
  <int>  <int>  <int>
1     1     36     35
2     2    246     87
3     3     33     14
```

Comment: While they still work, `spread` and `gather` were superseded [two years ago](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/09/tidyr-1-0-0/) with the release of `tidyr-1.0.0`, replaced by the more featureful `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider`. While they still work, they are no longer under active development. I do like the premise of pivoting longer into multiple columns (not just the one column in my answer), that could easily be very useful.